# Skip invalid records while processing CSV using Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have simple Camel route (Java DSL) configured to:

- Read a CSV file from a location.
- Unmarshal is using 'BindyCsvDataFormat'.
- Split it and push each record(row) to Kafka.

The route works fine in a happy path scenario.

But while reading the CSV if any of the records in the CSV are invalid the entire route fails and none of the records are processed. What I need is to skip the invalid record(row) and continue processing the other valid records and just log an exception for the invalid records.

Comment: How about if you split it first based on a "new-line" token (like \r), then unmarshal each line inside the split. This way each record becomes a message of its own, and you can do error handling or ignore on exceptions

Comment: @RaminArabbagheri I did try it but it doesn't work. If I split before un-marshalling I get an error.

'.when(header("CamelFileName").contains("Cap")
                .split().tokenize("\n")
                .unmarshal(capacityFeedCsvDataFormat)
                .split(body())
                .streaming()
                .bean(mapper, "convertAndTransformCapFeed")
                .split().tokenize("\n")
                .to(toMongoDB())
                .end();'

Error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No records have been defined in the CSV